# TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

i am facing an error while getting a list of services based on previous id of dropdown

***ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined***

here is my HTML

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>Team Member</td>
 <td>                  
 <select name="teamember" class="form-control" ng-model="members" ng-options="c.Name for c in member" ng-change="loadservices(members)"></select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Service</td>
 <td>
 <select name="service" class="form-control" ng-model="servicesforemp" ng-options="c.Name for c in sfe"></select></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

here is my Angular Controller

```
var app = angular.module('appointment', ['ngRoute']);
    function getMembers($scope, $http) {
        $scope.member = [];
        $scope.servicesforemp = [];
        $http.get('/api/servicesapi/GetEmpByBusiness')
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    $scope.member = response.data;
                    $scope.membrs = $scope.member[0];
                },
                function() {
                    
                }
            );

        $scope.loadservices = function (members) {
            var id = members.Id;
            console.log(id);//shows correct id
        //error :function exits here
            $http.get('/api/servicesapi/GetServicesByEmployees', id)
                .then(
                    function(result) {
                        $scope.servicesforemp = result.data;
                        $scope.sfe = $scope.servicesforemp[0];
                    },
                    function() {
                        alert('Error in loading services');
                    }
                );
        };
    }
```

Comment: try this `$http.get('/api/servicesapi/GetServicesByEmployees', {params: {id: id}})`

Comment: Where is "getMembers()" called ? That looks like a global function. I don't see where your controller gets created.

Comment: @CAT function is a simplest example of controller, you don't have to define it in `angular.module(..).controller()` method

Comment: @doodeec don't you have to at least use ng-controller ?

Comment: @CAT yes, but I'm assuming there is one outside of `<table>`, I believe this is just a snippet of problematic part of the markup

Comment: @doodeec you are absolutely right it is outside the table

Comment: @doodeec 
thanks it is working 
`$http.get('/api/servicesapi/GetServicesByEmployees', {params: {id: id}})`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen in a number of ways with improper use of `$http`. In my case, I was sending in an undefined url.

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: obj.thisIsUndefined
}).success ....
```

In your case @doodec is right:

```
$http.get('/api/servicesapi/GetServicesByEmployees', options)
```

Second argument to `get` should be a config object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get